# Почему static main()?

Tags: java

Почему метод `main()` должен быть статичным?

Comment: Потому что в java нет функций, а статические методы - их близжайший аналог. Почему же все таки статическая фукнция? потому что нельзя вызвать метод у объекта, который не создан.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146576/why-is-the-java-main-method-static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько возможных причин:

1. Для того чтобы не создавать экземпляр класса при при запуске - это лишние накладные расходы.
2. Это соглашение, как в СИ `void main()`

Answer (score 1):

Наверное потому что в системе сам метод main вызывается не из текущего контекста, а по имени класса.